# Unvoiced final "d" where it "should" be voiced -- regional accent question

Tags: phonology, accent, aspiration, endings

Native speaker here.
I don't have a problem with /d/, but somehow in words like "record", and in all -ed preterites, I voice it /t/, borderline aspirated.
My English is native (think, dream in English, etc) but I grew up among a bunch of different accents, so I'd like to know where I got that from.

Comment: Are you sure "record" is a good example? You say "recort"?

Comment: Voicing is independently innervated and uses independent muscles from mouth sounds, so, yes, it frequently stops before the phonation does at the end of a word. Entirely a matter of individual habit, which may (like any individual habit) become a feature of a speech group's lect.

Comment: About preterites in English: there are two final sounds for regular verbs (i.e. that end in ed): He walked or talked is a /t/. They fined us. or They mined a seam there. is /d/. All that is pretty standard. However, putting a /t/ on record (the verb to record or a police record) is not usual at all.

Comment: You're going to have to record it and put it in Praat to see if it really is unvoiced. It's possible also that you are interpreting an unreleased stop as unvoiced.

Comment: Thank you John Lawler, I hadn't considered it might be entirely idiosyncratic.

Comment: siride, I've had to record myself a lot for my job, that's how I noticed it. But I will put it in Praat when I have a little time. Also I'll research a little on "unreleased stops", I don't know what those are. Also I'll read Nardog's links.

Answer (score 2):

I assume what you're picking up on is [final-obstruent devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing#English). The "voiced" plosives aren't typically actually voiced unless surrounded by voiced sounds. When you say *bed* and *pet* in isolation, the consonants themselves are all (wholly or partially) voiceless. Onset /p/ is distinguished from /b/ by the period of [aspiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant) following the burst, and coda /t/ is distinguished from /d/ by the shortening of the preceding vowel ([pre-fortis clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(phonetics)#English)). Thus some refer to the "voiceless" [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) like /p, t, k/ and the "voiced" ones like /b, d, ɡ/ as ["fortis" and "lenis" consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortis_and_lenis), respectively, to avoid the rather misleading labels.

[Ladefoged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Ladefoged)'s *Vowels and Consonants* has a fun demonstration of the effects of (final-obstruent devoicing and) pre-forits clipping [here](https://www.vowelsandconsonants3e.com/chapter_10.html). Just by shortening the duration of the vowel, *bad* turns into *bat* in perception.

Comment: Thank you Nardog, I'll read those links when I have a little time.